# Count frequency of words in a given file

Tags: java, algorithm, strings, sorting

> Write a function that takes two parameters:
>
> 1. a `String` representing a text document
> 2. an integer providing the number of items to return
>
> Implement the function such that it returns a list of Strings ordered
>   by word frequency, the most frequently occurring word first.
>
> Runtime not to exceed \$O(n)\$

I decided to use a map to count the frequency of the words and then do the count sort to achieve sorting in linear time. Is this the best approach or there is some other solution that I am not aware of?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

interface IFrequencyCounter{
 public String[] getMostFrequenctWords(String content, int numberOfwords );
}

public class FrequencyCounter  implements IFrequencyCounter{

/**
 * This is the Frequency Class
 * which has only one property count.
 * This is used to save autoboxing/unboxing 
 * overhead when using maps. 
 */
private class Frequency{

private Frequency(){
    this.count = 1;
}

private int count;

public int getFrequency(){
    return this.count;
}

public void incrementFrequency(){
    this.count++;
}

public void setCount(int count){
    this.count = count; 
   }
}

/**
 * Token class extends Frequency. This is 
 * used to maintain word frequency relationship.
 * (Just like a pair.)
 */
private class Token extends Frequency{

private Token(String word, int count){
    super();
    this.word = word;
    setCount(count);
}

private String word;
}

/**
 * This method returns String array sorted by most frequent word. If null/empty     string
 * is provided as input then empty array is returned. If numberOfWords is greater then 
 * unique words then all the words are returned. 
 * 
 * @see com.evernote.util.IFrequencyCounter#getMostFrequenctWords(java.lang.String, int)
 */
@Override
public String[] getMostFrequenctWords(String content, int numberOfwords) {
    // basic validations
if( null == content) content = "";
if(numberOfwords <= 0) return new String[0];
int maxSofar = 0;
HashMap<String,Frequency> wordMap = new HashMap<String,Frequency>();

 String[] contentArray = content.split("\\s+");
 addWordsToMap(contentArray, wordMap);
 return getSortedArray(numberOfwords, maxSofar, wordMap);
}

 /**
  * returns sorted array of words(String) in decreasing order of frequency.
  * @param numberOfwords
  * @param i
  * @param maxSofar
  * @param wordMap
  * @param wordsArr
  * @return String[]
  */
 private String[] getSortedArray(int numberOfwords, int maxSofar, Map<String, Frequency> wordMap) {
String[] mostFreqWordsArr;
int i =0;
Token[] wordsArr = new Token[wordMap.keySet().size()];

for (String key : wordMap.keySet()) {
    wordsArr[i++] = new Token(key, wordMap.get(key).getFrequency());
    if(maxSofar < wordMap.get(key).getFrequency()){
        maxSofar = wordMap.get(key).getFrequency();
    }
}

wordMap = null; // just to free memory in case input is a very large string
int[] frequencyArr = new int[maxSofar+1];
String[] stringArr = new String[wordsArr.length];

for(i =0; i<wordsArr.length; i++)       frequencyArr[wordsArr[i].getFrequency()] += 1;
for(i =1; i<frequencyArr.length; i++)   frequencyArr[i] += frequencyArr[i-1];
for(i= 0; i<wordsArr.length; i++)   {
    stringArr[frequencyArr[wordsArr[i].getFrequency()]-1] =  wordsArr[i].word;
    frequencyArr[wordsArr[i].getFrequency()] -=1; 
}

if(stringArr.length-numberOfwords >= 0)
    mostFreqWordsArr = Arrays.copyOfRange(stringArr, stringArr.length-numberOfwords, stringArr.length);
else 
    mostFreqWordsArr = Arrays.copyOfRange(stringArr, 0, stringArr.length);

// reverse the string so most frequent words come first
for(i = 0; i < mostFreqWordsArr.length / 2; i++){
    String temp = mostFreqWordsArr[i];
    mostFreqWordsArr[i] = mostFreqWordsArr[mostFreqWordsArr.length-1 - i];
    mostFreqWordsArr[mostFreqWordsArr.length-1 - i] = temp;
}
return mostFreqWordsArr;
}

/**
 * @param contentArray
 * @param wordMap
 */
private void addWordsToMap(String[] contentArray, Map<String, Frequency> wordMap) {
for (String string : contentArray) {
    if(wordMap.containsKey(string)){
        wordMap.get(string).incrementFrequency();
    }else {
        Frequency token = new Frequency();
        wordMap.put(string,token);
    }
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Nicely done for homework.

Comment: Lets say if I want to use this code in production then are there any changes which I should make ?

Comment: That depends on you, if it works you can, if you want to go for more perfection, listen to the answers and refactor your code to it.

Comment: I believe the suggested solution runs in o(nlogn) complexity at the worst case due to the sorting of the map entries so seems to me it fails to answer the question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are a number of things in here you have done well, and your algorithm is good. I like that you have created an object to contain the frequency. Using the HashMap is the right solution too.

Overall, the OOP, and algorithm is good, but.... the presentation is messy, and there's a couple of things you can do better.

The indentation and code style in general are very inconsistent. I imagine you are using an IDE to write your code (based on the boilerplate JavaDoc comments), so, there is no real excuse for the inconsistent indentation. Maybe you had a problem pasting it in to Code Review... (I see this is your first question). There's a trick in Code Review (and all Stack Exchange sites). When editing your question, you can select the code, and click the "code" button, or press Ctrl-k to indent things 4 spaces to get the formatting right.

### Code Style

The indentation is a problem. Part of it is probably the pasting and manual fix up you may have done. But, even then, there are some lines indented one space more than I expect.

The bigger issue is the consistency and conformance-to-standards of where you declare your variables.

It is standard in Java for the class to have the class declaration, static fields, static methods, instance fields, the constructor, then public methods, finally private methods. There are some variations, but, the private variables should always be declared before the constructor....

While we are looking at this class, the variable should be final, and there is no need for the call to `super()` in the constructor.

The code:

> ```
> private class Token extends Frequency{
>
> private Token(String word, int count){
>     super();
>     this.word = word;
>     setCount(count);
> }
>
> private String word;
> }
> ```

should be:

```
private class Token extends Frequency{

    private String word;

    private Token(String word, int count){
        this.word = word;
        setCount(count);
    }

}
```

### Frequency

The good thing about Frequency is that you are using it. You are correct when you say it is better than the autoboxing system (keeping an Integer in the HashMap). I have to question why you felt it was necessary to add the intermediate class Token though. There is no need for them both. Choose one, and merge the other in to it. For example, there is no reason why you can't add the String value to the Frequency class. As it stands, the logic is a little bit too abstracted.

### Map efficiency

The code

> ```
> for (String string : contentArray) {
>     if(wordMap.containsKey(string)){
>         wordMap.get(string).incrementFrequency();
>     }else {
>         Frequency token = new Frequency();
>         wordMap.put(string,token);
>     }
>     } 
>   }
> ```

is not doing efficient HashMap lookups. Consider rewriting it like (only one lookup to the map):

```
for (String string : contentArray) {
    Frequency token = wordMap.get(string);
    if(token == null) {
        wordMap.put(string,new Frequency());
    }else {
        token.incrementFrequency();
    }
}
```

### Other....

- The variable `int maxSofar = 0;` and the maxSoFar parameter is useless, just initialize maxSoFar inside the `getSortedArray` method.
- Using a variable name `string` is a bad idea.

Comment: Woha.. awesome review. I liked it. Yes the formatting is bad because I did it after pasting and pressing space bar 4 times for most of the lines. Sorry for that. Also why is the other look up in may is better than the previous one ? Also I made two classes because I wanted proper abstraction. String class wasn't needed in map so I created two classes.

Answer (score 5):

### Naming

You should give variables and methods proper names:

**Consistency**
Your `Frequency` class contains a `getFrequency` method and an `incrementFrequency` method, but also a `count` variable and a `setCount` method.

Either rename `count` to `frequency` or the other way around (not including the class name of course).

**Typos**
It is a very awkward "oopsy" moment when you find a typo in your code, even more so if it is a method name which is already in use or overridden - so re-read your code and try to find them before they become harder to replace... (`getMostFrequenctWords` should be `getMostFrequentWords`)

**Convey meaning**
Your variable/parameter names should convey the meaning of what do they hold, and how they should be used.

`numberOfWords` is maybe technically accurate, but does not help the reader know what it is for. Perhaps `maxResults` would do a better job.

`getSortedArray` is also a little too generic, and `sortWordsByFrequency` might be more appropriate.

`addWordsToMap` is also very technical, and I think that `Map countWords(String[])` is more readable, and gives a better flow to the calling code.

**Don't be lazy**
In most cases it is a bad idea to shorten words in variable names, as they make the name less readable - don't use `Freq` - say `Frequency`.

**Don't repeat type in the name**
There is no need in repeating the type of a variable in its name - `mostFrequentWords` does not reduce anything by omitting the word `Arr` from it.

### Comments

When you have good naming to your classes, methods and parameters, you will find that most method comments are simply re-iterations of the method signatures. Likewise, when you find that a method/parameter needs extra explanation in a comment, it might be because it has a bad name.

So, `String[] getMostFrequentWords(String content, int maxResults)` is very self-descriptive, and doesn't actually need *any* documentation.

Comments have a nasty habit of rotting - when you change the code, you tend not the maintain the comments, which after awhile will stop describing the code, and sometimes even totally mislead the reader. (see `@param wordsArr`, for example)

### Encapsulation

Keep internal data of a method *inside* it - don't expose it in your signature. `maxSofar` and `wordMap` have no business in the method signatures. One is totally internal, and the other should be instantiated within the method and returned rather than passed by reference.

### Declare variables only when they are needed

There is no need to declare variables at the beginning of a method if they are only used at its end.

Comment: Very nice review. Thanks a lot Uri Agassi. I never thought it that way you mentioned and gave me a good insight to enhance my way of writing code. A great thanks to you again .